# Condition Based Data Rendering In Mustache.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I have Json data like

```
[{"Answer":"0"},{"Answer":"1"},{"Answer":"1"},{"Answer":"0"}]
```

I want to display right.png if the answer is 1 else i want to display wrong.png.

How Can I check the value of "Answer" before rendering the correct Image ? I am using Mustace.js template engine for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them true/false instead of 1/0. You can use [inverted sections](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/mustache.html#Inverted_Sections) to test against the boolean.

```
[{"Answer":false},{"Answer":true},{"Answer":true},{"Answer":false}]
```

and in your template:

```
<img src="{{#Answer}}right.png{{/Answer}}{{^Answer}}wrong.png{{/Answer}}" />
```

From [Doc](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

> An inverted section opens with {{^section}} instead of {{#section}}. The block of an inverted section is rendered only if the value of that section's tag is null, undefined, false, or an empty list.

*If you use handlebars.js it gives you more flexibility than this to specify if else conditions*